# <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> DLL load failed:

Tags: python

I got a python script that worked before but doesn't now. I have to run it despite never working with python before.

```
import sys
import packetlogic2
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring, ElementTree
#from ElementTree_pretty import prettify

host = "85.21.223.68"
user = "user"
password = "password"
startdate = "2017-02-27"
enddate = "2017-02-27"
path = "/http-domain-distribution?Statistics Object"
#vers = ["v15_1"]


try:
    pl = packetlogic2.connect(host, user, password, 42000)
    # pl.connect(host, user, password)
    s = pl.Statistics()
except:
    t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print "Couldn't connect to PacketLogic: t = %s, v = %s, tb = %s" % (t, v, tb)
    sys.exit(1)
```

the result of running it

```
Couldn't connect to PacketLogic: t = <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, v = DLL lo
ad failed: ═ÕÔÕ­ÝÓ  ´¯´¹‗ÛÓ õ¯±‗¾´Ó Û Óõ­Õ±¾ ´Óý ‗Þ., tb = <traceback object at
0x000000000261E6C8>
```

I use python 2.7.13 on windows, if that matters. What is this error and how do I run it?

Edit 13.03.2017

I changed python version to 32 bit and packetlogic2 to 32 bit. Started getting `error 10060`, but at least it's not `DLL load failed` Seems like there was a version problem.

Comment: You not compile a module from source, install a ready for use module but where `system_register_point` ? don't use `packetlogic`(use `ctypes.windll`) or reinstall related module from source code(recompile).

Comment: @dsg by module, do you mean this? `from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring, ElementTree`. What do you mean by `but where system_register_point ?`

Comment: `packetlogic2` under `system32` if calling from `os` OR `C:\\Python27\scripts\xxx.dll` if calling from `python`.

Comment: @dsg I still don't understand. Are you trying to say that the problem is in `packetlogic2`  and that I need to recompile it? That is impossible as I only have an exe file for it. How do I use ctypes.windll?

Comment: @dsg `from ctypes import *
windll.LoadLibrary("what do I write here?")` This way? what do I write in the brackets?

Comment: This not perfect way if related DLL call another DLL/resource, Try add `sys.path.append` where_your_related_dll.